# reactjs session with mysql data not working after build

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I've created a react project, on my local instance it's working but when I build it and deployed to production, the code did not get the data from the database.

I used axios and called the php file in the js file. And I tried adding proxy in package.json but nothing happened.

**config.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

 $host = "192.168.2.127:3336";
 $user = "root";
 $password = "welcome";
 $dbname = "hi";
 $id = "";

 $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);

 $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
 $request = explode('/',trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']));

 if(!$con){
  die("Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

 ?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

 require 'config.php';

 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $division = $_POST['division']; 
 $company = $_POST['company'];

 $comp = mysql_query("SELECT comp_id FROM company WHERE comp_name = 
 '".addslashes($company)."'");
 $comp_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($comp);

 $div =  mysql_query("SELECT div_id FROM division WHERE division_name = 
 '".addslashes($division)."' AND comp_id LIKE '.addslashes($comp_id).'");
 $div_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($div);

 $userName = mysql_query("SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = 
 '".addslashes($username)."'");
 $user_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($userName);

 $userpass = mysql_query("SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = 
 '".addslashes($username)."' AND user_password = 
 PASSWORD('".$password."')");
 $user_password = mysql_fetch_assoc($userpass);

  $div =  mysql_query("SELECT div_id FROM division WHERE division_name 
 '".addslashes($division)."' AND comp_id = '".$comp_id['comp_id']."'");
 $div_id = mysql_fetch_array($div, MYSQL_ASSOC);

 $query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = 
 '".addslashes($username)."' AND user_password = PASSWORD('".$password."') 
 AND comp_id = '".$comp_id['comp_id']."' AND div_id = 
 '".$div_id['div_id']."'");
 $user = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
 $num = mysql_num_rows($query);
 if($comp_id === '' || empty($comp_id)){
   echo 'No Company';
 }elseif($div_id === '' || empty($div_id)){
   echo 'No Division';
 }elseif($user_name === '' || empty($user_name)){
   echo 'No User';
 }elseif($user_password === '' || empty($user_password)){
   echo 'Not Match';
 }elseif($num === 1){
   echo json_encode($user);
 }else{
   echo 'No Record';
 }
 ?>
```

**Login.js**

```
handleClick = event =>  {
event.preventDefault();

if (this.validateForm()) {
  let loginform = document.getElementById('login');
  let formData = new FormData(loginform);
  formData.append('username',this.state.username)
  formData.append('password',this.state.password)
  formData.append('company',this.state.company)
  formData.append('division',this.state.division)

  axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 
  this.getHostname()+'/new_vehicle_management/src/components/php/login.php',
  data: formData,
  config: 
  {
    //headers:{'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": 'true', 
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, 
 OPTIONS',
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      Accept: "application/json"
  }}
  })
  .then(function (response) {
          if (response.data === "failed") {
           alert("Connection Failed.")
          }else if (response.data === "No Company") {
            alert("Company does not exist.")
           }else if (response.data === "No Division") {
            alert("Division does not exist.")
           }else if (response.data === "No User") {
            alert("Username does not exist.")
           }else if (response.data === "Not Match") {
            alert("Username and Password does not match.")
           }else if(response.data === "No Record"){
            alert("Invalid Credentials.");
           }
           else{
            alert("Login Successfully")
            localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(response.data))
            localStorage.setItem('user_id', 
 JSON.stringify(response.data.user_id))
            localStorage.setItem('user', 
 JSON.stringify(response.data.user_full_name))
            localStorage.setItem('div_id', 
 JSON.stringify(response.data.div_id))
            localStorage.setItem('comp_id', 
 JSON.stringify(response.data.comp_id))
            //window.location = "/menu"
           }
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response)
        });
     }         
  }
```

Comment: Why you added the CORS settings on the client? I'm referring to `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers. Those must be returned from server in the response.

Comment: Ok, we'll try to remove the header on the php files. Do you think that's the reason why I can't connect to the database when in production?

Comment: Well it's easy to spot the issue if you're facing bad configs for your CORS. Just check the browser console and it will tell you if it's failing to fetch data from the server. But from what you provided it's hard to spot the issue.

Comment: I suggest to replicate the app on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) as simple as possible, that way some might be help you find the issue faster.